# Type.GetFields() - only returning "public const" fields

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I want to call Type.GetFields() and only get back fields declared as "public const".  I have this so far...

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
```

... but that also includes "public static" fields.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Trying checking whether [`FieldInfo.Attributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.attributes.aspx) includes [`FieldAttributes.Literal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldattributes.aspx). I haven't checked it, but it sounds right...

(I don't think you can get *only constants* in a single call to `GetFields`, but you can filter the results returned that way.)

Answer (score 37):

```
type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public).Where(f => f.IsLiteral);
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting from .NET 4.5 you can do that

```
public class ConstTest
{
    private const int ConstField = 123;

    public int GetValueOfConstViaReflection()
    {
        var fields = this.GetType().GetRuntimeFields();
        return (int)fields.First(f => f.Name == nameof(ConstField)).GetValue(null);
    }
}
```

I checked and it looks like fields has all private consts.